# How can I use EventMachine for asynchronous Thrift communication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, thrift, eventmachine

Currently I'm using synchronous communication between a Rails app and HBase using Thrift protocol:

```
table = HBaseRb::Table.new ThriftClientFactory.create("client_name"), "table_name"
i = table.atomic_increment("row_key", "f:count_#{Time.now.getlocal.hour}")
```

Those codes are in a model class, so the service can be **blocked** if HBase has some problem.

To solve this, I'd like to make Thrift communication asynchronously (non-blocking I/O). I thought [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) can solve this problem. But there're several questions about using EventMachine to my Rails app:

1. As far as I know, an EventMachine is like a server(or daemon) which listens to events continuously. If so, should I include a small EM server to my Rails app?
2. Should I use `EventMachine.start_server :host, : port, :server_module` to do what I want?  If so, is **HTTP request** the way I send events to the EM server?

If I understand EM incorrectly, please let me know.

Thanks for any advices/corrections.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to implement a HTTP server. EM runs a reactor and listens to events. This is done by the method `run`. Once the reactor starts, you can specify how the events are handled. IMO, look into [EM.defer](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/EM::Deferrable-and-EM.defer)

Comment: In case you are running a web application, EM loop may be have been started for you transparently. Consider using em_synchrony and rack-fiber_pool ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12583515/202914). Unfortunately, there's no EM adapter for HBase yet (I haven't found one at least in the [list](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Protocol-Implementations)). So EM.defer (spawns a `Thread`) seems to be the only choice.