# No perfomance gains from using em-http-request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

I'm trying to understand how to use various non-blocking IO libraries in Ruby and made a simple app for testing using Sinatra,

```
# proxy.rb
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/synchrony'
require 'faraday'

class ProxyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Synchrony

  get "/proxy" do
    conn = Faraday.new("http://mirror.yandex.ru") do |faraday|
      faraday.use Faraday::Adapter::EMSynchrony
    end
    conn.get "/ubuntu-releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso"
    "Hello, world"
  end

  get "/" do
    "Hello, world"
  end
end
```

As far as I understand, downloading a file using non-blocking IO should allow other requests to execute, but it doesn't - if I'm using `ab` to open `/proxy` path (I'm using Thin as an app server), request to `/` takes a very long time. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinatra::Synchrony? Why?

config.ru:

```
require File.join Dir.pwd, 'proxy.rb'
run Proxy
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'thin'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'em-synchrony'
gem 'em-http-request'
gem 'rack-fiber_pool'
```

proxy.rb:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

class Proxy < Sinatra::Base
  use Rack::FiberPool

  get "/proxy" do
    conn = Faraday.new("http://mirror.yandex.ru") do |faraday|
      faraday.use Faraday::Adapter::EMSynchrony
    end
    conn.get "/ubuntu-releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-i386.iso"
    "Hello, world"
  end

  get "/" do
    "Hello, world"
  end
end
```

Start:

```
thin start -d
wget localhost:3000/proxy
```

In another terminal:

```
wget localhost:3000/
```

The reply is immediate for /, no matter how many requests to /proxy you do in parrallel.

Comment: I saw the ilya's post about untangling evented code. But can you explain, why it works in this special case? Will it suspend the current EM Fiber by calling yield on it, within `con.get` ? And why i don't have to put this into `EM.snynchrony do` block?

Comment: @dre-hh Correct. It yields somewhere in the deeps of [EMSynchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony/blob/master/lib/em-synchrony/em-http.rb) itself. You only perform a single request, so `do` block is optional. And I suspect that it's also possible to use `Faraday::Adapter::EMHttp`. And also drop `Rack::FiberPool`, had some bad experiences with it.